# Make No Response status for http calls

Tags: c#, http, web, request

I have implement Get() for http get requests. And I am making a rest call to that function with some authentication headers. When supplied with valid authentication headers, it works. But When I use invalid header, I should get "No Response" in my rest client. This needs to implement. Could anyone say what should do for this. 
I am using DHC ReST client chrome extension as my Rest client. Given below the GET implementation

```
public stream Get()
{
  if(WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Authorization"))
  {
    //Validating the header
    ...
    if( valid header)
    {
       WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/xml";
       byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
       var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

       stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       return stream;
    }

    if(invalid header)
    {
      //I need to generate no response codes from here.
      //I tried, throw exception, change status code, return null stream but nothing worked.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please clarify what server technology & version are you using to handle the http request

Comment: I am developing a C# Desktop application which based on WCF. I am creating a Responder for http requests.

Comment: If you catch the "no response" in "if (invalid header)" what do you mean by handling it? Do you get a status code back when you use invalid header?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I need to get status code back in my Rest client.

Comment: Yes It worked. Actually I tried many status codes including Not found, Bad requests, But Didn't tried 'OK'. Thank you all for your time.